# Not able to redirect my pages to index.php in WAMP SERVER

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, wampserver

I have copied my code from LINUX (which is perfectly working) to Windows where I am using WAMP server to practice web development. I don't understand why my pages are not being redirected to index.php.

dev.mysite.com is working and showing my home page, which means doc root is correct and working fine. Later pages are showing 404 because of this redirect issue. Below is my .htaccess, can someone please check and advice, where I am doing wrong?

For example, if I am trying to access dev.mysite.com/contr1/action1 I am getting 404 not found.

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([^/]+)/?$ app/$1-$2/$3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems enabled. I got internal server error

Answer (score 0):

For Local Development servers you cannot use tld's like .com, .org, .net, etc. without doing additional very complex things, which I will not go into. See this well explained tutorial on setting up Virtual Hosts, hosts file, etc. in WAMP: https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/